# Generating a noisy sine wave in Python, efficiently

Tags: noise, python, wave

(Questions after code block.)

For now, I am generating the sinusoid and the noise separately and then normalising the amplitude so I can write the signal to a .wav file (16-bit, 16kHz).

```
def genSine(f0,fs,dur):
    sinusoid = []
    for t in range(dur):
        sinusoid.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*t(*freq/fs)))
    sinusoid = normalise(sinusoid)
    return sinusoid

def genNoise(dur):
    noise = np.random.normal(0,1,dur))
    noise = normalise(noise)
    return noise

def normalise(x,MAX_INT16):
    maxamp = max(x)
    amp = floor(MAX_INT16/maxamp)
    norm = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        norm[i] = amp*x[i]
    return norm

def writeWav(w):
    # audiophilic magic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f0 = 440
    fs = 16000
    dur = 1*fs                      #seconds
    MAX_INT16 = 32767
    sinusoid = genSine(f0,fs,dur)
    noise = genNoise(dur)
    sum = x + y
    sum = normalise(sum,MAX_INT16)
    writeWav(sum)
```

1. Is there a more efficient way to sum the two signals (sine + noise), perhaps bypassing/incorporating the normalisation step (it is currently called three times, in genSine, genNoise and main)?
2. How can I ensure set the amplitude ratio between the sine and noise signals?

I'm new to Python and stackexchange so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are some ways to improve your solution.

First, use `numpy` and vectorize your code:

```
def genSine(f0,fs,dur):
    sinusoid = []
    for t in range(dur):
        sinusoid.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*t(*freq/fs)))
    sinusoid = normalise(sinusoid)
    return sinusoid
```

becomes

```
import numpy as np
def genSine(f0, fs, dur):
    t = np.arange(dur)
    sinusoid = np.sin(2*np.pi*t*(f0/fs))
    sinusoid = normalise(sinusoid)
    return sinusoid
```

You will see the biggest improvment in efficiency when vectorizing all your code like this.

Second, concerning the normalization, you should consider the mathematics of your problem instead of doing it 3 times. You have 3 pieces of signal, the sinusoid, the noise, the mix. The first is already normalized (between -1 and 1), the second also (hence the name normal distribution for describing the noise). So you should only normalize the third.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, the normal distribution leads to a signal with Gaussian distribution that has unit variance. The amplitude of the signal is not restricted to a maximum.

Comment: I said normalized, not *bounded* - for clarity let's not confuse different norm definitions. I do not see how that desserves a down vote, anyway :-)

Comment: Not my downvote :-)

Comment: Thanks meduz! I had a feeling it was something essential like numpy... (Not my downvote either, btw)

Comment: why isn't there something like awgn (https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html) in python?